# HtmlUnit missing formal parameter

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to scrape a website using HtmlUnit but it throws an exception. I can't disable JavaScript because the website is built in Angular. Setting `ThrowExecutionOnScriptError` to `false` doesn't help. I have tried all browser versions. Any thoughts?

```
//imports
public class Scrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url="https://www.gog.com/games?page=1&sort=popularity&price=discounted";
        WebClient client=new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        HtmlPage page=client.getPage(url);
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
//      List<HtmlElement> items=page.getByXPath("div[@class='product-tile']");
//      if(items.isEmpty()) {
//          System.out.println("Nothing  found");
//      }else {
//          for(HtmlElement i:items) {
//              System.out.println(i.asText());
//          }
//      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please open an issue on github.

Comment: For anyone experiencing similar problems here's a link to the github issue https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/232